# bom characters appearing after upgrade to wampserver 2.4

Tags: php, soap, character-encoding, wampserver, soap-client

I was running wampserver 2.4 previously and all api functions were working well, however now when I use soapClient I am receiving the error with a couple of web services that we access.

"looks like we got no XML document"

After researching this for quite some time, it looks like there is BOM characters in the response, however the previous version worked quite well. I can't downgrade back to previous version because I require the 5.4.x  version of php for other parts of code in the project.

When I output the last session, it is missing the final > from the soap envelope response.
In the other api I had issues with, it was causing bom characters at the start of the response. Quite frustrating.

I have tried changing settings in php.ini and httpd.conf however it is just not helping.

I made a "hack" for one soap response which extends SoapClient, but this only works sometimes, and is not practical to use across all projects which I manage.
it was based on something I saw on here, and does work for some responses but not others.

```
  public function __doRequest($req, $location, $action, $version = "SOAP_1_1"){
  $response =   parent::__doRequest($req, $location, $action, $version );
   $response = preg_replace( '/^(\x00\x00\xFE\xFF|\xFF\xFE\x00\x00|\xFE\xFF|\xFF\xFE|\xEF\xBB\xBF)/', "", $response ) ;
    $response = mb_convert_encoding($response,  "UTF-8",'HTML-ENTITIES');
    if (substr($response,-1) != ">"): $response .= ">";endif;
    return $response;
}
```

Sometimes there is a random entity within the body of the response also, which seems to cause some issues too.

At this stage I've wasted 2 whole days looking into this, but am unable to find anything with a solution that will allow these responses to be read correctly.

I tried adding 
    AddDefaultCharset utf-8
    DefaultType application/xml
to httpd.conf

and in php.ini i put in
    default_charset = "utf-8" 
and also tried

```
zend.multibyte = 1
detect_unicode = 1
zend.script_encoding = 1
```

wampserver 2.4 is using apache 2.4.4 and php 5.4.12

If anyone can help me with this and assist me in preserving my sanity it would be fantastic. thank you.